# Taxonomy Term Image 'post_per_page' doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

This code working with image and title but post_per_page doesn’t work and trying
`number' =>1`
is work but if any taxonomy Less than one Or equal to one Info will not be showing.

```
                <?php 
                    $tax = 'studio';
                    $types = get_terms( array( 
                        'post_per_page' => 1,
                    )
                );
                    foreach($types as $type) { ?>
                    
                    <?php 
                        $term_link = get_term_link( $type );
                        $image = get_field('studio_avatar', 'studio_' . $type->term_id . '' ); 
                        if ( has_term( $type->term_id, 'studio')) {

                            echo '<a class="author author-avt inline" href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">';
                                echo '<img class="si-user" src="' . $image['url'] . '" /> ';
                                echo '<span>'. $type->name . '</span>';
                            echo '</a>';
                            
                            echo '<span class="posted-on inline">';
                                echo '<i class="si-clock"></i><time>'. $post_date = get_the_date("j F Y") .'</time>'; 
                            echo '</span>';   
                        }    
                    ?>
                 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `posts_per_page` doesn't work because isn't a valid argument for `get_terms`. `number` should work for 1 or more... obviously if there are < 1 results there is nothing to show!

Comment: Is there any other way?